# Question about functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an inner product space. $z \in X$ fixed. Let $f(x) = \langle x,z\rangle$. Suppose the mapping $X \to X' $ given by $z \to f $ is surjective. Does it follow that $X$ is a Hilbert space?

$X'$ is the dual space of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because your mapping is also linear and isometric, and $X'$ is complete.

Comment: How is it isometric? I cannot see that

Comment: Isometry follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: It is standard that $\|f\|=\|z\|$. You use CS and that $f(z/\|z\|)=\|z\|$.